# Import Export API | StartImport Fails always with "Aborted" process state

Tags: sdl-tridion, sites-9.1, importexportservice

I have tried importing only one item at a time.

- a single item(component),
- a single image,
- a single page

but call to StartImport() always fails with an "Aborted" state as seen below:

Call to StartExport() works and I am able to download the package and the logs file too.

Is there any settings/configuration I need to update for Import to work?

Also, in the EventViewer, I see logs getting generated for Export Process Start/Finish, but for Import Process there is nothing getting logged in Event Viewer.
[image]

@Rick Import Instruction used by Me. Tried commenting/uncommenting various flags but still same issue.

Also, I am uploading package to server before trying import. Uploading to server also succeeds and I get a packageName uploaded on server as something "import_a2beff.."

[image]

Comment: What you code fragment currently doesn't show:
* Did you upload the package to the server first?
* What's the `importInstructions` you use?

Comment: @Rick I have uploaded a screenshot of the import instructions I am using. Also, I am uploading the package to server before trying import.

Comment: Any warnings/errors in Tridion Event Log?  Try setting `RunInTransaction = false`

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest hint here is:

> Also, in the EventViewer, I see logs getting generated for Export
> Process Start/Finish, but for Import Process there is nothing getting
> logged in Event Viewer.

If there is no log generated for import process in EventViewer, it surely means you are not importing to this particular server. Please check to which server are you importing the package ?

Also, as Rick already mentioned and to add further to his point, Uploading package is done on same server where you will run the Import and NOT export.
Are you sure your `_clientImportService` is initialized/using endpoints of Import Server ?

One reason of `"Aborted"` process state is because the package was not uploaded
[package not found] on import server before starting the Import process.

Other reasons for `"Aborted"` process state can be BluePrint issues, dependencies missing in export package etc...